# Convert a map with houses into a graph

Tags: graph, maps, graph-theory, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am curious how map software (Google/Bing maps) convert a map into a graph in the backend.

[image: Image of a graph and a map]
Now if we add houses between intersections 1 and 2, then how would the graph change. How do map software keep track of where the houses are?

Do they index the intersection nodes and also have smaller "subnodes" (between 1 and 2 in this case)? Or do they do this by having multiple layers? So when a user enters a home number, it looks up where the home is (i.e. between which vertices the home is located). After that, they simply apply a shortest path algorithm between those two node and at the beginning and the end, they basically make the home node go to one of the main vertices.

Could someone please give me a detailed explanation of how this works? Ultimately I would like to understand how the shortest path is determined given two the "address" of two "homes" (or "subnodes").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak for GraphHopper, not for the closed source services you mentioned ;)

GraphHopper has nodes (junctions) and edges (connection between those junctions), nearly exactly how your sketch looks like. This is very fast for the routing algorithms as it avoids massive traversal overhead of subnodes. E.g. in an early version we used subnodes everytime the connection was not straight (e.g. curved street) and this was 8 times slower and so we avoided those 'pillar' nodes and only used the 'tower' nodes for routing.

Still you have to deal with two problems:

- How to deal with queries starting on the edge at e.g. house number 1? This is solved via introducing virtual nodes for every query (which can contain multiple locations), and you also need the additional virtual edges and hide some real edges. In GraphHopper we create a lightweight wrapper graph around the original graph (called [QueryGraph](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/routing/QueryGraph.java)) which handles all this. It then behaves exactly like a normal 'Graph' for every 'RoutingAlgorithm' like Dijkstra or A*. Also it becomes a bit hairy when you have multiple query locations on one edge, e.g. for a route with multiple via points. But I hope you get the main idea. Another idea would be to do the routing for two sources and two targets but initialized with the actual distance not with 0 like it is normally done for the first nodes. But this makes the routing algorithms more complex I guess.
- And as already stated, most of the connections between junctions are not straight and you'll have to store this geometry somewhere and use it to draw the route but also to 'snap a location to the closest road' do finally do the actual routing. See LocationIndexTree for code.

Regarding the directed graphs. GraphHopper stores the graph via undirected edges, to handle oneways it stores the access properties for every edge and for every vehicle separately. So we avoid storing two directed edges and all of its properties (name/geometry/..), and make the use case possible "oneway for car and twoway for bike" etc. It additionally allows to traverse an edge in the reverse direction which is important for some algorithms and e.g. the bidirectional Dijkstra. This would not be possible if the graph would be used to model the access property.

Regarding 'nearly exactly how your sketch looks like': node 1, 3, 7 and 8 would not exist as they are 'pillar' nodes. Instead they would only 'exist' in the geometry of the edge.

Answer (score 0):

To represent the connectivity of a road network, you want your directed road segments to be the graph nodes and your intersections to be collections of directed edges. There is a directed edge from X to Y if you can drive along X and then turn onto or continue on Y.

Consider the following example.

```
a====b====c
     |   
     | <--one way street, down
     |
     d
```

An example connectivity graph for this picture follows.

- Nodes

  ```
  ab
  ba
  bc
  cb
  bd
  ```
- Edges

  ```
  ab -> bc
  ab -> bd
  cb -> ba
  cb -> bd
  ```

Note that this encodes the following information:

- No U-turns are allowed at the intersection,
  because the edges `ab -> ba` and `cb -> bc` are omitted.
- When coming from the right a left turn onto the vertical road is allowed,
  because the edge `cb -> bd` is included.

With this representation, each node (directed road segment) has as an attribute all of the addresses along its span, each marked at some distance along the directed road segment.